# Custom cursor not working correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm having trouble getting chrome to display my custom cursor correctly but it seems to work as intended in FireFox.

To give a little context, as part of my attempt to get up to speed with HMLT5/Javascript I'm putting together a mini shooting game using the new canvas element and I'm using a custom scope-like cursor I created with Axialis Cursor Workshop and here's the html and css for the canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="block" width="800" height="700"
        onSelectStart="this.style.cursor='url(cursors/scope.cur), crosshair'; return false;"/>

#canvas
{
    cursor: url(../cursors/scope.cur), crosshair;
    background: url(../images/canvas_background.jpg);
}
```

In chrome, I see a warning saying "*Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream.*" in relation to the *scope.cur* file. When I move my mouse to the top left corner of the canvas area I can see the cursor is drawn but the 'hot spot' of cursor is not at the center of the cursor.

In firefox, this works with no problem, I can still see the same cursor and the 'hot spot' of the cursor is at its center as I intended.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here and how can I fix it for chrome? The standard *crosshair* cursor works fine in chrome (in that its 'hot spot' is positioned correctly) but it doesn't quite fit my purpose here.

You can see for yourself [here](http://www.theburningmonk.com/demos/shooting%20target/part%202/shooting_target_demo_part_2.html), just move the cursor to the top left corner in chrome and firefox to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved this problem in the end though it's a bit of a hack.

I first tried using a blank cursor but then Chrome renders that as a black square.. so I decided to draw the target as part of the canvas and use a cursor which has hotspot at 0, 0 and is blank EXCEPT the 0, 0 tile which has the same colour as the target.

You can see the result [here](http://canvasblank.theburningmonk.com) once you start the game, it's not a pretty solution, but works nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

To solve the "Resource interpreted as image..." warning:

- Create a text file named `.htaccess`
- Write this command:
      `AddType image/vnd.microsoft.icon .cur`
- Save in folder `/cursors` OR in any parent-folder (typically the site root `/`)

This should work on *Apache* server.

[Here a post](http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/cursor-mime-media-type) about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two different problems here.

1. The first ("Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream.") should be fixed server-side. The server must send scope.cur as image MIME, not octet-stream. You could try to change the format of the .cur file (i.e. .png) or you could write a .htaccess file with the right MIME.
2. There should be  and  properties for CSS3 "cursor": http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor, but I have tried this in Chrome and it does not seem to work:

   cursor: url(../cursors/scope.cur) -10px -10px, crosshair;

Comment: I found something about this here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12244

Comment: Hi Lorezo, thanks for the reply, there's no 'server side' as per se, and if I change the file to a .png wouldn't I lose the hot spot information in the cursor file anyway?

Comment: I think that the CSS standard doesn't use the hot spot information into .cur files.

Answer (score 1):

My reply is probably way too late by now but this should work in chrome:

`cursor: url(../cursors/scope.cur) 4 4, crosshair;`

You might also need to write a little script that checks for browser types using the jQuery `$.browser` property.

Read this: [Cross browser css - grab cursors for dragging/](http://www.jaycodesign.co.nz/css/cross-browser-css-grab-cursors-for-dragging/)

Note: I believe MIME type problem has already been addressed.

Comment: jQuery $.browser is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/). I would raccomend using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) instead.

Comment: @BBog - Yeah, I hear Modernizr does a better job at handling cross browser issues.