# Chrome hover custom cursor

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, cursor

I am using a custom cursor for my project. The custom cursor works perfectly in IE and FF, but in Safari and Chrome it works, but the hoverstate defaults back to the pointy hand. I ensured that I use each and everything selector possible to ensure it uses the pointer for this cases, but no success. Does anyone else have a possible solution? The CSS I use is:

```
#gameScreen area, #gameScreen .wrapper, #gameScreen .wrapper a:hover, #gameScreen img, #gameScreen img a:hover, #gameImg, #gameImg area, #gameImg area a, #gameImg area a:hover, #gameImg a, #gameImg a:hover, #gameImg img a:hover {
    cursor: url(cursor.cur), url(images/cursor.cur), default;
}
```

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773312/custom-cursor-not-working-correctly-in-chrome, might be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any feasible solution except to use jQuery, hide your cursor and then create an empty div which should then "follow" your mouse cursor using the .css() method in jQuery.

Not a pleasant work around but it works.