# Custom cursor is appearing as black square

Tags: html, asp.net

I have written below code in my ASP.NET website to use the custom cursor. This works fine in IE 10 but shows black square in chrome.

```
element.style.cursor = "url(WebResources/CustomPointer.gif),auto";
```

Can someone please look into this advise as I have spent good time to fix this but nothing worked...

Comment: What size is that cursor (there appears to be a browser-dependent limit)? Is it an animated gif? Could you convert to png and try again?

Comment: _"as I have spent good time to fix this but nothing worked..."_ - explain _what_ you have tried, so people won't have to resuggest the same things.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623769/css-custom-cursor-doesnt-work-in-ff-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773312/custom-cursor-not-working-correctly-in-chrome

Comment: sorry for the typo actually I am using .cur file (not gif) and code is something like below                                               

 element.style.cursor = "url(WebResources/CustomPointer.cur),auto";

The size of .cur file is 1 kb and having hot spot 5,5

It works with png and gif file but doesn’t with .cur file in chrome and firefox. But in my project I have to use only .cur file for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `.cur` file, this is probably because you're using the "inverse" palette color in the cursor file (which is represented in the binary file as `FF`), which Chrome and Firefox don't support.  They support the normal palette and setting the hotspot, but not the "inverse" color.